# Multiple strings in one label

Tags: objective-c, string, uilabel

I have a label that needs to display two strings. At the moment I have this:

```
     self.artistLabel.text = self.string1;
```

I want to be able to display string 1 and string 2. if possible, I also need to have an "@" symbol in between the two strings. I know it must be simple, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
self.artistLabel.text = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@"
,   self.string1
,   self.string2
];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, cheers. I also added the "@" in between the two strings by simply having: `stringWithFormat:@"%@ @ %@"`

Comment: @user3429966 you should get a warning if you use the single @ and using xcode.

Comment: @MiloGosnell No you won't. There's nothing special about the `@` symbol in a string format unless it is preceded by the `%` symbol. Now a single `%` is bad. It needs to be `%%` if you want an actual `%` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a new string from both string1 and string2 with an "@" in the middle
NSString *artistLabelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@@@%@", self.string1, self.string2];

//Set the label
self.artistLabel.text = artistLabelString;
```

Just as a BTW, the `@@` in the middle gives you a single `@`.

Comment: This is incorrect. You only need one `@` to get an actual `@` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can display only one string in one UILabel. However, that string can itself be a combination of multiple strings.

To combine strings, look into methods like `stringByAppendingString:`.